# Escape double quotes in json in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I am receiving a json object from a webhook.  I use JSON.stringify to change to string to store in MySQL table.  Later I retrieve it from the MySQL table.  I run JSON.parse over it.  then use the data to create a text message in NodeJS.  The problem arises when I have double quotes in a product title.  JSON.parse does not like them in NodeJS.

I replaced the " with \".  Then ran JSON.parse and it worked perfect but this was done manually.  I need this to be on auto - having code in NodeJS do this versus manually.

Original JSON

```
"line_items":[{"id":853139563,
"taxable":true,
"title":"“Fuel” Natural Fish Food - "Fuel" Natural Fish Food",
"total_discount":"0.00",
"vendor":"Aqua Design Innovations"}]
```

Needed Result JSON - Around the word "Fuel" is now \"Fuel\" in title

```
"line_items":[{"id":853139563,
"taxable":true,
"title":"\"Fuel\" Natural Fish Food - \"Fuel\" Natural Fish Food",
"total_discount":"0.00",
"vendor":"Aqua Design Innovations"}]
```

Comment: Your `Original JSON` is not a valid json.

Comment: The webhook you're using is giving you invalid JSON. The best solution would be to get the maintainer of that webhook to fix that. If that's not an option, you're left having to use a kludge to cope with the invalid json and attempt to convert it into something usable.

Comment: Yes I understand it maybe invalid but I have no control over it.  It's coming from Shopify and there is no way they are going to fix it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to find all the string values of key-value pairs and then replace all 'internal' quotes with literals.

At the end of the code, we successfully parse the string into a JSON object. See comments below for explanation:

```js
let jsonStr = '{"line_items":[{"id":853139563, "taxable":true, "title":"“Fuel” Natural Fish Food - "Fuel" Natural Fish Food", "total_discount":"0.00", "vendor":"Aqua Design Innovations"}]}'

// this matches for all string values in the key-value pair
let strVals = jsonStr.match(/(?<=":")([^:]+?)(?="(?=,|}|]))/g) //[ '“Fuel” Natural Fish Food - "Fuel" Natural Fish Food','0.00','Aqua Design Innovations' ]

strVals.forEach(strVal => {
    // we replace all quotes with literal quotes
    let newVal = strVal.replace(/("|“|”)/g,'\\"'); 
    // then replace the new value back to original string
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(strVal,newVal);
})

console.log(jsonStr); //{"line_items":[{"id":853139563, "taxable":true, "title":"\"Fuel\" Natural Fish Food - \"Fuel\" Natural Fish Food", "total_discount":"0.00", "vendor":"Aqua Design Innovations"}]}

let json = JSON.parse(jsonStr); 

console.log(json); 
/*
{ line_items: 
   [ { id: 853139563,
       taxable: true,
       title: '"Fuel" Natural Fish Food - "Fuel" Natural Fish Food',
       total_discount: '0.00',
       vendor: 'Aqua Design Innovations' } ] }
 */
```

Regex explanation:

> `(?=":")`  looks behind for `":"` pattern which then begins our match
>
> `[^:]+?` we look for any number of characters excluding `:`, up till the lookahead
>
> `(?="` looks ahead to a closing `"` which is immediately followed by next lookahead
>
> `(?=,|}|])` next lookahead for either `,` or `}` or `]` which confirms it's the end of the value string

Comment: Pretty convoluted way to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. The real solution is to fix the reason behind OP's broken JSON. Not to fix the JSON once it's already broken.

Comment: The OP posted a problem, this answers the problem. No need to downvote it.

Comment: OP's question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Giving them a kludge to fix the symptom rather than the root problem is bad advice. And I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer.

Comment: Be that as it may, the author is receiving the bad JSON from a webhook. We don't don't whether he has control of the webhook or not. If he has, then asking him to fix it there is better advice. That still doesn't make this a bad answer *per se*, just suboptimal. If he doesn't have control, then this answer works great. Not a good enough reason to deserve a downvote imho.

Comment: Ok, I misread the question. It sounded like OP was producing the JSON, but upon reading it again, I see that they are re-serializing it and deserializing that. Given that, I agree that they may have no other choice, but as I said, the downvote isn't from me.

Comment: Chatnoir - AWESOME!!!  I will try this.  I really appreciate the help!!!!  As far as to others - I have no control over this.  Yes you are right it's invalid JSON but there is NO WAY Shopify will fix this.  There is one way to fix - have store owner change the Title of product to have no double quotes but that is not an option since we deal with many stores.